# smooth $0$-form

Tags: calculus

Is $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$  smooth on [0,∞) ?

I think, it is not. $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$  is continuous  on [0,∞) and smooth on (0,∞) (without boundary), but $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is not smooth on [0,∞) because $df/dx$ is not continuous at $0$.
Is that true?

Comment: The right derivative does not exist at $0$.

Comment: So, it is not smooth on [0,∞). Is that correct?